# How to stop query automatically after a few seconds in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this procedure. The procedure in calling another procedure.
I need to stop the inside procedure if it takes more than few seconds, but I can't use the stop button because it inside another procedure

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[proc_1]
as
begin

declare @id output
exec proc_2 @id

if no return for 5 seconds
stop proc_2 automatically

exec proc_3 @id


end
```

know lets say proc_2 is trying to update a locked for editing table and therefore delaying.
I want to stop it and perform proc_3 before I have all the time allotted for the main procedure
But what should I write for: if no return 5 seconds stop the procedure?

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: You can't do this; T-SQL is a strictly sequential language and once something's running you can't stop it from the same session. To work around this you'd need to do things like script creation of jobs. For the purpose of locking specifically, look at `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT` (and `TRY ... CATCH` to handle the error condition).

Comment: What you want is a processing overwatch engine built into a simple procedure. With normal commands in SQL Server such functionality is not possible. There are system process tables available that can be queried with an overwatch engine but an answer is very technically detailed and long and probably involves CLR or outside applications.

Answer (score 0):

I set lock_timeout to return if proc_2 in stuck
with try and catch. the exec of proc_3 is in the catch

```css
CREATE procedure [dbo].[proc_1]
as
begin

declare @id output

begin try
begin transaction
set lock_timeout 1000
exec proc_2 @id
commit transaction
end try

begin catch
exec proc_3 id
end catch


end
```